# You are trying to add a non-nullable field '_response_rendered'; django-markupfield

Tags: django, django-models

Upon wanting to add some Markdown to a project, I've decided to install *django-markupfield* to serve this objective. The only thing is that I've installed my models and associated fields ahead of making this decision; now replacing a `TextField` with `MarkupField`.

When attempting to make a migration to adjust for this, the following is brought up:

```
You are trying to add a non-nullable field '_response_rendered' to answer without a default; we can't do that (the database needs something to populate existing rows).
Please select a fix:
 1) Provide a one-off default now (will be set on all existing rows with a null value for this column)
 2) Quit, and let me add a default in models.py
```

What would be an appropriate default value to add to the fields that will be prompting for such? I have never been too sure of this question in general when it comes to using Django as well, so clarification would be appreciated.

https://github.com/jamesturk/django-markupfield

```
class Question(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    body = MarkupField(
        markup_type="markdown",
        escape_html=True
    )
    dated = models.DateField(default=date.today)
    user_account = models.ForeignKey(
        'users.UserAccount',
        on_delete=models.SET_NULL,
        null=True, blank=True,
        related_name="questions"
    )
    tags = models.ManyToManyField(Tag, related_name='questions')

    objects = models.Manager()
    dateranges = DateRangeQuerySet.as_manager()
    status = QuestionStatusQuerySet.as_manager()

    class Meta:
        ordering = ['-dated']
        default_manager_name = "objects"

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title



class Answer(models.Model):
    question = models.ForeignKey(
        Question,
        on_delete=models.CASCADE,
        related_name="answers"
    )
    response = MarkupField(
        markup_type="markdown",
        escape_html=True
    )
    dated = models.DateField(auto_now_add=True)
    user_account = models.ForeignKey(
        'users.UserAccount',
        on_delete=models.SET_NULL,
        null=True, blank=True,
        related_name="answers"
    )
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to add default value.

In the background **[`MarkupField`](https://github.com/jamesturk/django-markupfield/blob/48c7e5122dbd4c962d5cd94074cf95c356340d6d/markupfield/fields.py#L151)** create two fields ([source link](https://github.com/jamesturk/django-markupfield/blob/48c7e5122dbd4c962d5cd94074cf95c356340d6d/markupfield/fields.py#L12)):

> ```
> _rendered_field_name = lambda name: "_%s_rendered" % name  # noqa
> _markup_type_field_name = lambda name: "%s_markup_type" % name  # noqa
> ```
>
> ```
> class MarkupField(models.TextField):
>     
>     ...
>
>     def contribute_to_class(self, cls, name):
>         if self.rendered_field and not cls._meta.abstract:
>             ...
>             cls.add_to_class(_markup_type_field_name(name), markup_type_field)
>             cls.add_to_class(_rendered_field_name(name), rendered_field)
>         super(MarkupField, self).contribute_to_class(cls, name)
>
>         setattr(cls, self.name, MarkupDescriptor(self))
> ```

The simple solution is provide default value at the time of migration:

- So select choice **1** and enter default value. It will be add
  default value **only** for the current migration, so your field is
  **non-nullable**. Argument [**`preserve_default`**](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/migration-operations/#addfield)([Django Docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/migration-operations/#addfield)) will be added.

Or provide `default` value in **models.py**:

```
class Question(models.Model):
    ...
    body = MarkupField(
        markup_type="markdown",
        escape_html=True,
        default="SOME VALUE"
    )
    ...



class Answer(models.Model):
    ...
    response = MarkupField(
        markup_type="markdown",
        escape_html=True,
        default="SOME VALUE"
    )
    ...
```

You can always remove `default` attribute and run `makemigrations/migrate` again.

**THE BEST PRACTICE IS CREATE BACKUP BEFORE YOU RUN:**

```
python manage.py makemigrations
python manage.py migrate
```

Answer (score 0):

Try adding `null = False` to your field and migrate again. This usually works for me!